# Trying to connect to MySQL through the command line, but getting MariaDB instead

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm currently trying to learn PHP and MySQL from scratch. I've downloaded the very latest [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) and started completing some small projects. Everything is going great. Every project I've done so far uses [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) and I've found it quite fun. However, I'm now trying to do some more advanced projects. These tutorials use the command line to connect to MySQL rather than phpMyAdmin.

I've never used the command line before, so I was eager to learn, but here is my problem. When I do the standard connection to MySQL I don't connect to MySQL like the tutorials. I instead connect to [MariaDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB). Once I'm connected the next commands in the tutorial no longer work and I don't know what to do.

Being new to PHP, I'm following these tutorials line for line and using Google to research problems. However, this one I can't find an answer to. No books or tutorials I've seen mention MariaDB.

Is MariaDB different to MySQL? If so, how do I learn the commands?
Would it be easy to use MySQL instead? How do I do this?

Simply put, everything I'm currently using as a resource to learn PHP and MySQL has not mentioned MariaDB. When I search on Google I can't really find much on MariaDB that answers my questions. I'm struggling to work out what I should be doing to complete this projects and continue learning PHP.

Comment: xampp bundles mariaDB since some version ago. mariaDB is a drop-in replacement for mysql, it shouldn't differs much. perhaps you could share what kind of command you tried?

Comment: As Tezla mentioned, it would be helpful if you would provide the command you tried and the error message you got, otherwise this is really too general to be of much use for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB is a [drop in replacement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/) for MySQL. You shouldn't have any problems using MariaDB instead of MySQL. The things you're gonna use with MySQL will 99% of the times also work with MariaDB.

When searching for answers, just google for your MySQL-errors and correct. Your code will work even though you use MariaDB instead for MySQL for the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the command-line versus phpMyAdmin, you should be able to stay in phpMyAdmin and use its SQL panel to type your commands.